Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@microsoft/signalr"
I recently begun implementing Signal R into our ASP.NET Core MVC App (.NET 6). I am facing this error regarding my import statement in my .ts file.
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

connection.start().then(() => {
    console.log("Connection established!");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.toString());
});

Setting up SignalR has been simple enough with javascript, but i am struggling to get it up and running using typesript, following the official docs.
The mentioned typescript file is being built to javascript everytime i save the file, and that javascript file is referenced in my "_Layout.cshtml" file.
I am unsure what i am doing wrong, as if i follow the documentation to use a javascript file for the client it works perfectly in implementing signalr. Thanks in advance, let me know what other questions you may have.
Setup: Installed node module @microsoft/signalr via npm. It is correctly showing in my "node_modules" folder.

What is the error?

@SoftwareDveloper the title contains the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@microsoft/signalr""

Could you create a brand new front-end repo for us checking ? And let us know the nodejs version and typescript version in your local.
